# i have an issue on sapper export with js interaction

Tags: svelte, sapper

i have an issue on sapper.
When i export my static website `npm run export` through **browser-sync** work correctly, when i put it on server, svelte does not work.
From network tab i see the js files are correctly loaded but the interaction does not work, I tried loading a simple component, just a button that emit a console.log but nothing happens.
i didn't find anything about it on other questions.

I've tried with other framework, nuxt, next and gatsby too with the static generation.
nuxt and sapper are the only that make me problems.

Comment: Where are you serving the site, Netlify, Vercel? And are you serving the contents of the `__sapper__/export` folder?

Comment: i'm serving the page on gcloud through FTP load, and yes i'm serving the __sapper__/export folder